# Nativescript Slider Value Delayed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, slider, nativescript

I created a metronome, using the Nativescript Slider (https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/slider.html) to set the speed (interval).

This code works just fine (the speed changes correctly in realtime):

*app.component.html*

```
<Slider #sl minValue="10" maxValue="350" [(ngModel)]="interval" (valueChange)="setInterval(interval)" row="0" col="1"></Slider>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
public metronome = sound.create("~/pages/metronome/click.mp3"); 
public interval: number = 120;
public timer: number;

start(){
    this.stop(); // Stop previous metronome
    this.tick();
}

stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
}

setInterval(interval: number) {
    this.interval = interval; 
}

public tick() {
    console.log("Tick");
    this.metronome.play();
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), this.interval);
}
```

But with this code above, the metronome uses ms (milliseconds) instead of bpm (beats per minute). Musicians want to set the metronome in BPM.

Therefore: `ms = 60'000 / BPM` (see => this.plainInterval)

```
setInterval(){
    this.plainInterval = 60000 / this.interval;
}

public tick() {
    console.log("Tick");
    this.metronome.play();
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), this.plainInterval);
}
```

NOW my problem:
As I use the slider, the value doesn't update correctly.

i.E.: The slider-default is 120. Okay. Then I slide to 60. The value still remains at 120... Then I slide to 200 and NOW the value jumps to 120. I can continue and slide to 10, NOW it's 200.

SO: The problem is, that it retrieves the old value. And as a set a new value, the old one get's triggered.

How can I synchronize the `plainInterval` and `interval` to solve the problem?

Comment: `As I use the slider` - you seem to have posted code that has no reference to this mythical `slider` you are actually having problems with - can't help you debug code that you don't post

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code. It's the Nativescript Slider (https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/slider.html)

Comment: Being in an Angular-2 application you should use only ngModel for your two-way binding - no need to do the same job with valueChanged which is triggered after the ngModel (which I thnk is causing your values to be "step" behind from what you would expect)

Comment: @NickIliev Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Because: The variable of the slider (`this.interval` => Now in BPM) is the same as the variable for the TimeOut (Now in ms)... If I set the slider to 120 (this.interval = 120), the component calculates 60000/120=500 and sets this.interval 500, now I have the right TimeOut for .tick(), but the wrong value for the slider, which jumps to 500 (but in fact it shouldn't show 500 `ms`, but 120 `BPM`). Do you understand my problem? I think I somehow need an observable...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem!
`this.interval` has a Two-Way-Databinding through `[(ngModel)]="interval"`. That means I can't use `this.plainInterval`, because it's not directly connected to the Two-Way-Databinding of `this.interval`.
I first tried to use a Pipe, but it's not allowed with 2-Way-Databinding `[(ngModel)]`. Therefore I used my prototype (but working) code (I provided in the beginning) and only adjusted the value of setTimeout in `this.timer`. This is the working code:

```
start(){
        this.stop();
        console.log("START: " + this.interval);
        this.tick();
    }

stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
}

setInterval(interval: number) { // This function isn't required
    this.interval = interval; 
}

public tick() {
    console.log("Tick");
    this.metronome.play();
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 60000/this.interval); // This was the only change needed: 60'000 / this.interval 
}
```